Azure function not getting executed when it is added as skillset in AI search
I had an existing AI Search resource. I added a new filed in the index called top_words. Then I created a skillset as Azure Function which count words from a document and add the value in the new field of the index.



After creating the skillset and index, I ran the indexer.
However, when I query the index, the top_words value is coming as null. What I might have missed here?

Update
One issue I found is that I didn't add the new field in the field mapping.
After adding the following object in outputFieldMappings array,
{
  "sourceFieldName": "/document/topWords",
  "targetFieldName": "top_words"
}

when I reset the indexer and ran it again, I see error  Could not map output field 'top_words' to search index. Check the 'outputFieldMappings' property of your indexer.
However, top_words field exists in the index.

Following are the files
- function

    module.exports = async function (context, req) {
        context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request. req:'+JSON.stringify(req));
    
        if (req.body && req.body.values) {
            
            vals = req.body.values;
    
            // Array of stop words to be ignored
            var stopwords = ['', 'i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', 
            "youre", "youve", "youll", "youd", 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 
            'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 'she', "shes", 'her', 
            'hers', 'herself', 'it', "its", 'itself', 'they', 'them', 
            'their', 'theirs', 'themselves', 'what', 'which', 'who', 'whom', 
            'this', 'that', "thatll", 'these', 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was',
            'were', 'be', 'been', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 'do', 
            'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 
            'because', 'as', 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at', 'by', 'for', 'with', 
            'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 'through', 'during', 'before', 
            'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 'out', 
            'on', 'off', 'over', 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 
            'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 
            'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 
            'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 'can', 'will',
            'just', "dont", 'should', "shouldve", 'now', "arent", "couldnt", 
            "didnt", "doesnt", "hadnt", "hasnt", "havent", "isnt", "mightnt", "mustnt",
            "neednt", "shant", "shouldnt", "wasnt", "werent", "wont", "wouldnt"];
    
            res = {"values":[]};
    
            for (rec in vals)
            {
                // Get the record ID and text for this input
                resVal = {recordId:vals[rec].recordId, data:{}};
                txt = vals[rec].data.text;
    
                // remove punctuation and numerals
                txt = txt.replace(/[^ A-Za-z_]/g,"").toLowerCase();
    
                // Get an array of words
                words = txt.split(" ")
    
                // count instances of non-stopwords
                wordCounts = {}
                for(var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
                    word = words[i];
                    if (stopwords.includes(word) == false )
                    {
                        if (wordCounts[word])
                        {
                            wordCounts[word] ++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wordCounts[word] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                // Convert wordcounts to an array
                var topWords = [];
                for (var word in wordCounts) {
                    topWords.push([word, wordCounts[word]]);
                }
    
                // Sort in descending order of count
                topWords.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return b[1] - a[1];
                });
    
                // Get the first ten words from the first array dimension
                resVal.data.text = topWords.slice(0,9)
                  .map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });
    
                res.values[rec] = resVal;
            };
    
            context.res = {
                body: JSON.stringify(res),
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    
            
    
            };
            context.log('returning res :'+JSON.stringify(res));
        }
        else {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: {"errors":[{"message": "Invalid input"}]},
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            
    
    
            };
            context.log('returning error res :'+JSON.stringify(context.res));
        }
    };

- indexer.json

    {
      "@odata.context": "https://aisearchdemomc.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
      "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCA8159277DA50\"",
      "name": "margies-indexer",
      "description": "Indexer for Margies Travel",
      "dataSourceName": "margies-data",
      "skillsetName": "margies-skillset",
      "targetIndexName": "margies-index",
      "disabled": null,
      "schedule": null,
      "parameters": {
        "batchSize": null,
        "maxFailedItems": -1,
        "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": -1,
        "base64EncodeKeys": null,
        "configuration": {
          "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
          "parsingMode": "default",
          "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
        }
      },
      "fieldMappings": [
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
          "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
          "mappingFunction": {
            "name": "base64Encode",
            "parameters": null
          }
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
          "targetFieldName": "url",
          "mappingFunction": null
        }
      ],
      "outputFieldMappings": [
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/locations",
          "targetFieldName": "locations"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content/keyphrases",
          "targetFieldName": "keyphrases"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/language",
          "targetFieldName": "language"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/merged_content",
          "targetFieldName": "merged_content"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/text",
          "targetFieldName": "text"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/layoutText",
          "targetFieldName": "layoutText"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageTags/*/name",
          "targetFieldName": "imageTags"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/normalized_images/*/imageCaption",
          "targetFieldName": "imageCaption"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/sentimentLabel",
          "targetFieldName": "sentiment"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldName": "/document/topWords",
          "targetFieldName": "top_words"
        }
      ],
      "cache": null,
      "encryptionKey": null
    }

- index.json

    {
      "@odata.context": "https://aisearchdemomc.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
      "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCA5D377A7CBE6\"",
      "name": "margies-index",
      "defaultScoringProfile": null,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "content",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_content_type",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_size",
          "type": "Edm.Int64",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_last_modified",
          "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_content_md5",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_name",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_path",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": true,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_storage_file_extension",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_content_type",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_language",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_author",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": true,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_title",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata_creation_date",
          "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "locations",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "language",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "keyphrases",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "merged_content",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "text",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "layoutText",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "imageTags",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "imageCaption",
          "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "sentiment",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "url",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "top_words",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "stored": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchProfile": null,
          "vectorEncoding": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        }
      ],
      "scoringProfiles": [],
      "corsOptions": null,
      "suggesters": [],
      "analyzers": [],
      "normalizers": [],
      "tokenizers": [],
      "tokenFilters": [],
      "charFilters": [],
      "encryptionKey": null,
      "similarity": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
        "k1": null,
        "b": null
      },
      "semantic": null,
      "vectorSearch": null
    }


you share your index , Azure Function code and the skill you added in text formate

sorry, I don't follow. Do you want me to put the index, code and skill in json in the question?

Yes in json format

The issues were with mappings.
The FunctionApp was sending the following output
{"values":[{"recordId":"a1","data":{"top_word":["tiger"]}},{"recordId":"a2","data":{"top_word":["rain"]}}]}

then I created a field in indexer
top_word StringCollection

In the skillset I added the input and output to/from the skill
{
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "get-top-words",
      "description": "custom skill to get top 10 most frequent words",
      "context": "/document",
      "uri": "https://customskillfunctionappmc.azurewebsites.net/...",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "degreeOfParallelism": null,
      "authResourceId": null,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/merged_content"
        },
        {
          "name": "language",
          "source": "/document/language"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "top_word", <- name from functionapp json
          "targetName": "top_word" 
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {},
      "authIdentity": null
    }

then I added mapping between indexer's output and index's field in indexer's outputFiledMapping
{
  "sourceFieldName": "/document/top_word", <-- output of skillset
  "targetFieldName": "top_word" <-- field in index
}

